# C program using getopt can't resolve url parameter

Tags: c, http, curl, libcurl, getopt

I'm trying to use getopt to enter a url from the command line to be used with HTTP get, post, put, and delete. HTTP GET was working earlier but for some reason I can't figure out how to resolve the url so that HTTP GET is successful now. When I print the url, it shows that it's in the expected format but curl complains saying the hostname could not be resolved. Can someone explain to me how to go about solving this issue and how to make it so only the first url entered in the command line gets accepted? Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<getopt.h>
#include<curl/curl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define OK 0
#define INIT_ERR 1
#define REQ_ERR 2

// function for HTTP GET
void get(char* url, CURL *curl, CURLcode res) {
    long http_code = 0;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[CURL] Could not execute HTTP GET: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            //return REQ_ERR;
        }
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
        printf("[HTTP CODE]: %ld\n", http_code);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}

// function for HTTP PUT
void put() {

}

// function for HTTP POST
void post() {

}

// function for HTTP delete
void delete() {

}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int c;
    char *content, *url; 
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    while(1) {
        static struct option long_options[] = 
        {
            {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
            {"get", no_argument, 0, 'g'},
            {"url ", required_argument, 0 , 'u'},
            {"post", required_argument, 0, 'o'},
            {"put", required_argument, 0, 'p'},
            {"delete", required_argument, 0, 'd'},
            {0,0,0,0}
        };

        // getopt stores option index here
        int long_index = 0;

        c = getopt_long_only(argc, argv, "hgo:p:d:u:", \
            long_options, &long_index);

        // detect end of options    
        if(c == -1)
            break;

        switch(c) {
            case 'h':
                printf("\n[HELP] Usage: ./test [VERB] 'content' [URL] <url>\n\n");
                printf("----------------------- HELP OPTIONS -----------------------------------------\n\n");
                printf(" FLAGS      ARGUMENTS   EXAMPLE ARG FORMAT      SUMMARY\n");
                printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("-h/--help   N/A     N/A             help options\n");
                printf("-g/--get    N/A     N/A             [VERB] http get option\n");
                printf("-o/--post   'content'   'Post this stuff.'      [VERB] http post option\n");
                printf("-p/--put    'content'   'Put this stuff.'       [VERB] http put option\n");
                printf("-d/--delete 'content'   'Delete this stuff/'        [VERB] http delete option\n");
                printf("-u/--url    'url'       'http://www.cnn.com'        [URL] http url of server\n");
                printf("                'http://localhost:PORT' \n");
                printf("                'http://IPADDRESS:PORT'\n\n");
                printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("            Example USAGE\n");
                printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("HTTP GET -  ./test --get --url 'http://www.cnn.com\n");
                printf("HTTP POST - ./test --post 'Post this content.' --url 'http://localhost:8080\n");
                printf("HTTP PUT -  ./test --put 'Put this content.' --url 'http://localhost:8080\n");
                printf("HTTP DELETE -   ./test --delete 'Delete this content.' --url 'http://localhost:8080'\n\n");
                break;
            case 'g':
                printf("[HTTP GET]\n");
                url;
                get(url, curl, res);
                break;
            case 'u':
                url = optarg;
                printf("[HTTP URL] url: %s\n", url);
                break;
            case 'o':
                content = optarg;
                printf("[HTTP POST] content: %s\n", content);
                break;
            case 'p':
                content = optarg;
                printf("[HTTP PUT] content: %s\n", content);
                break;
            case 'd':
                content = optarg;
                printf("[HTTP DELETE] content: %s\n", content);
                break;
            case '?':
                //getopt_long already printed error message
                break;
            default:
                abort();
        }
    //get(url, curl, res);
    }

    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Does `get()` work if you just call it with a hard-coded URL string?  If so, then people just need to look at the `getopt` code.  If not, then the `getopt` stuff is unnecessary clutter (for the problem you're having).  Note that you pass in a `res` and a `curl*`, but updating those within the function doesn't help with getting them out of the `get()` function since C passes arguments by value. In other words, those arguments are useless to `get()`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, if I hard code the url string under case 'g' the HTTP GET request works properly.

Comment: What is the command line you're testing?

Comment: @MichaelBurr __./test -g__ works with hardcoded url. When I pass the url I use __./test -g --url 'http://localhost:8000'__ and __./test -g --url "http://localhost:8000"__

Comment: What is the command line you're using to test with a URL on it?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I put http:// before localhost but stack overflow is dropping it off. Not sure if that's what it does in my program too but the print statement shows the correct url entry under case 'u'

Comment: The problem is that you put the `-g` option before the `--url` option so `get()` is called before the url is obtained.  Try: `./test --url "whatever" -g`

Comment: @MichaelBurr When I use that format I get 'Could not connect to server'

Comment: You're saying that:  `./test --url "hxxp://localshot:8000" -g` returns the error 'Could not connect to server', but if you hard-code the `get()` call as `get("hxxp://localhost:8000", curl, res);` it works (where "hxxp" is really "http" in both cases)?  If that's the case I'm not sure what's going on - I'm not at a system that will build a Curl app at the moment, so someone else might need to help with this part.

Answer (score 0):

as @MichaelBurr points out, -g should be given after --url /-u according to this code. I tried ./test --url "hxxp://google.com" -g and is working.
You may need to check the localhost:8000

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ended up getting it to work that way as well. Could you explain why that is or how I could make it accept the URL after the verb flag?

Comment: in case 'g':, you are calling get() function which ignores rest of arguments (after get() call, rest of arguments will be processed). Solution: process all arguments passed before you call get/post/put.